# -ms-high-contrast: active не работает в браузере Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прописал все префиксы -ms-grid, так же использовал

> @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast:
>   none) {}

Работает во всех браузерах прекрасно, кроме Edge.
Даже в IE 10 и 11 все на своих местах. 
В чем может быть проблема ? 
Для Edge разве что-то другое необходимо использовать ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-ms-high-contrast - секция Remarks (в самом низу)

Answer (score 0):

[MDN говорит](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-ms-high-contrast), что в Edge это `-ms-high-contrast: none` не работает, а вместо него нужно использовать `-ms-high-contrast-adjust`.

> As of Microsoft Edge, -ms-high-contrast: none is no longer supported.
>
> The -ms-high-contrast media feature works with the -ms-high-contrast-adjust property.
>
> The -ms-high-contrast media feature was introduced in Windows 8.

Comment: Спасибо ! К сожалению, такое решение тоже не помогло, но нашел другой способ : @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {}

Comment: @ДимаШамаль оформляйте как ответ, может кому-то поможет.